# Change regex's result order after sed as order of ls -v

Tags: sed, regex, xml

I am working on 53 xml files (`az-0.xml` ~ `az-52.xml`).

And I ran`sed '/<loc>/!d; s/[[:space:]]*<loc>\(.*\)<\/loc>/\1/' az-*.xml > AZ` to get all stuff in `<loc>` and merge them in 1 file (`AZ`).

It works fine, but I found the stuff in loc **has wrong  and Messy order**. 
I want to merge them in the right order like the output of `ls -v` (By Numbers).

```
az-0.xml az-1.xml ... az-52.xml
```

How can I give `-v` option to that regex? (I am very new to `sed`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed regex is not involved here, it's about the collation order of the `az-*.xml` shell glob expansion.

If you have `zsh`, then you could use the `n` numeric glob qualifier

```
sed '...' az-*.xml(n) > AZ
```

If you need to use bash then it doesn't have an equivalent numeric glob flag, but you could use an external version `sort` ex.

```
printf '%s\0' az-*.xml | sort -zV | xargs -0 sed '...' > AZ
```

or (if you know exactly how many files there are) a simple shell loop with a brace expansion

```
for f in az-{1..52}; do sed '...' "$f"; done >> AZ
```